# Can GDAL report if a .tiff is tiled or not?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, gdalinfo

A certain piece of software that I use doesn't support .tiff DEM's that are tiled. Is there a way with a GDAL utility to determine if a .tiff DEM is tiled or not?

```
gdalinfo dem.tif
```

will report the compression type and the interleave type (band/pixel), but as far as I can tell, the interleave type doesn't have anything to do with tiling.

you can translate the tiff DEM with a creation option flag to make an untiled DEM, but that requires a translation and not just a report.

```
gdal_translate -co TILED=NO dem.tif dem_notile.tif
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't found any specific commandline utility that can report if a tiff is tiled or striped. At least not directly or in a grepable form like `TILED=YES`.

There should be enough information in `gdalinfo` to make that decision, however.

I have a landsat scene, each made with gdal_translate:

`landsat_tiled.tif` : `-co TILED=YES`

`landsat_notiled.tif`: `-co TILED=NO`

```
gdalinfo landsat_tiled.tif | grep -E 'Block=|Size is'
>>Size is 7621, 7791
>>Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray

gdalinfo landsat_notiled.tif | grep -E 'Block=|Size is'
>>Size is 7621, 7791
>>Band 1 Block=7621x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

So it is obvious that tiled tiffs have a Y block size greater than 1. Striped tiffs have X block size equal to XSize and Y block size equal to 1.

This should be enough to determine if they are striped (not tiled).

```
gdalinfo landsat_notiled.tif | grep -o 'Block=.*x1\s'
>>Block=7621x1
```

If that call returns anything, you can be sure it is NOT tiled.

This doesn't address very small tiffs, which can have the entire raster array stored in a single block. So YMMV on those..

Comment: I just created a tiled 50x1 tiff with `gdal_translate -srcwin 0 0 50 1 -co tiled=YES input.tif test_tiled.tif`. `gdalinfo` still reports `Block=256x256` so your method will work for small tiffs as well.